# No module named django-filter

Tags: django, django-filter

I am trying to use django-filter. But it errors with no module named django-filter. Thanks for help.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    #,
    #,
    #,
    'django-filter',

]
```

I'm using:

> django-filter     2.4.0

Answer (score 0):

A module can not have a hyphen in the module name, so `django-filter` makes no sense. You use `django_filters` as specified in [the documentation on `django-filter` <sup>[readthedocs.io]</sup>](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/install.html):

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # …,
    'django_filters',
    # …
]
```